# How can I unlink objects that contain Field Imports from my application's MEF container?

Tags: .net, mef

I am writing a WPF application that uses MEF in .Net 4.  My app has a CompositionContainer that is accessed by all my view models in order to get access to (using MEF) some shared objects that are responsible for data retrieval and storage.

I have been using a memory profiler to look at the lifetime of some of both my view model objects as well as the data access objects to see when everything is being garbage collected.  To my surprise, I found that my app's CompositionContainer was keeping a reference to my view models after they had already been disposed.

The following is my attempt to show roughly how I'm using MEF.  I'm hoping someone can show me how I'm doing it wrong.

Code in App.xaml.cs

> ```
> public partial class App : Application
> {
>     private static CompositionContainer _container;
>     internal static CompositionContainer Container { get { return _container; } }
>
>     private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
>     {
>         AssemblyCatalog catalog = new  AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
>         _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
>     }
> }
> ```

Contract interface

> public interface ICostCentreService : IBaseEntityService
>      {
>          ...
>      }

Exported class that implements interface

> [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
>      [Export(typeof(ICostCentreService))]
>      public class CostCentreService : BaseEntityService, ICostCentreService
>      {
>          ...
>      }

My view model class

> public class CostCentreViewModel: ViewModelBase
>      {
>          [Import]
>          private ICostCentreService _costCentreService;
>
> ```
>    public CostCentreViewModel()
>    {
>        App.Container.ComposeParts(this);
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Hopefully the code extracts above paint enough of a picture as to show how I am using MEF.  The problem occurs once I have finished using the view model and I call Dispose and remove all references to it, it doesn't get garbage collected because the app's container still references it. (In the case I have on my screen at the moment, the memory profiler says my view model is still referenced by App._containner._partExportProvider._parts._items[0]._cashedIntance).

So I'm wondering how I get rid of this reference.  Am I not using MEF properlly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Nick Barrett

Answer (score 0):

Shared parts won't be released until the container is disposed.  A shared part means that only one will be created per container.  The MEF container keeps a reference to it because if it is ever asked for that part again, it should return the one that was already created instead of creating a brand new one.

For NonShared parts, there are ways you can have MEF release the references to them.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the reply.  I think I mustn't have done a very good job explaining the problem.  It's not the shared part that I was expecting to be garbage collected, it was my view model that imports the part that seems to linger on even though my code no longer references it.  This appears to be because the container seems to have some link to it.

Comment: @toomeke All parts are shared by default, so the container would hold references to both the ViewModel and whatever part the ViewModel imports.

Comment: Thanks again for responding.  I'm not surprised that the CompositionContainer keeps a reference to my ViewModel.  I presume it is so that it knows who it has composed imports for.  What I am surprised about is that there seems to be no way to get it to drop this reference.  It just feels a bit leaky to me.  As I have removed all references to my ViewModel in my code and have even called Dispose on it, for what purpose does the CompositionContainer have to keep it's reference to it?

Comment: @toomeke Like I said it keeps a reference so that it can hand it out if anything requests the same ViewModel in the future.  Shared means that if that happens it should return the same instance, and the container has no way of knowing whether it will be requested again or not, so it has to keep the reference.

Comment: Maybe this is where my initial explanation of the situation has fallen short.  The ViewModel itself is not instantiated by MEF.  I instantiate it myself in code.  Only the ViewModel's imports are composed by MEF. So MEF shouldn't need a reference to my ViewModel because it didn't create it.  I can still see that MEF may need to know who it has composed parts for (which is what I assume it is keeping the reference for) but I can't see any way to remove it. Sorry if I haven't done a very good job of explaining the problem, and thanks again for taking the time to try and help me.